# Print raw html to xls file in php

Tags: php, excel

I am trying to create a xls file in php. And I am making a string in html format lets say `<table><tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td></tr></table>` and want to print in xls file as it is. but My problem is that when I try to print in xls file its getting render. but I want raw html string without rendered in xls file.

Here is my code:-

```
<?php
$file="demo.xls";
$test="<table><tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td></tr></table>";
header('Content-type: application/excel');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
echo $test;

?>php
```

Comment: Naming a file *.xls does not magically make an excel file

Comment: Yes i agree with you .. its a forceful excel conversion and results in data formatting error sometimes

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a service called DocRaptor which does html to excel conversion. http://docraptor.com/ , Multiple language supported

Or You can use the below code to download the file in Excel but first you have to download the PHPExcel class files and include like below .

```
require_once "excel/Classes/PHPExcel.php";

$objTpl = new PHPExcel();

$l=0;
$row_num = 1;
$objTpl->getActiveSheet()->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setName('Calibri');
$objTpl->getActiveSheet()->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setSize(10);

$objTpl->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
$objTpl->getActiveSheet()->duplicateStyle($objTpl->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1'), 'B1:Z1');
$objTpl->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:Z1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);



// you can use loop over here remember to set $row_num = 2 if using loop and increment it inside $row_num++

$objTpl->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($l++,$row_num, 'Cell 1');

$objTpl->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($l++,$row_num, 'Cell 2');

$filename='some_file.xls'; //just some random filename
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); 

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objTpl, 'Excel5');      //downloadable file is in Excel 2003 format (.xls)

$objWriter->save('php://output');  //send it to user, of course you can save it to disk also!

exit; //done.. exiting!
```

Comment: The op `want to print in xls file as it is`. Not sure if this satsfies the requirement

Answer (score -1):

There is a way by either writing html in file or comma separated text 
**With HTML**

```
$xlsx_file = $pathinfo['dirname']."/".$pathinfo['filename'].".xlsx" ;

$fh = fopen($xlsx_file, 'w+');<br>
fwrite($fh, $table); // your table <br>
fclose($fh);<br>
```

**with array or string of csv**

```
 $data = '"Name"t"City"t"Country"' . "n";<br>
 $data .= '"Ashok"t"New Delhi"t"India"' . "n";<br>
 $data .= '"Krishna"t"Bangalore"t"India"' . "n";<br>

 $f = fopen('data.xls' , 'wb');<br>
 fwrite($f , $data );<br>
 fclose($f);<br>
```

this is temporary solution but if you want full set of options you go for PHP Excel as suggested by others